# VBA Excel wb.Close/wb.Open

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I’m hesitant to ask this here, but won’t have any hair left soon.
I have an Access database that the membership office keeps up to date. I reference queries of that data from here.

Membership saves reports per chapter and this report process grabs an Excel coversheet (xlsx) and copies (xls) tabs from active, existing reports for active chapters, shuffles them into query sequence, before saving the workbook to PDF. Not every chapter has the same reports at all, let alone each time reports are run, so I am happy so far with the approach, at least conceptually.

I am seeking help – admittedly, I’m not a good programmer, but like to learn. all suggestions welcome – concerning what I believe to be an access or privilege problem moving in and of excel by chapter. In concept, it seems to work fine if I don’t manipulate files or if I just have one active chapter. When it grabs the second chapter value and loops after taking care of the first. Set arWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=rptPathFile, ReadOnly:=True) seems somehow not to happen it fails out in mnpltRpts().

```
Public strChptrName As String
Public strChptrTag As String
Public strFileCPT As String


Private Sub rptLoop()

Dim dbsChActv As DAO.Database
Dim rstActvRpts As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstActvChptrs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qryActvRpts As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qryActvChptrs As DAO.QueryDef

Set dbsChActv = CurrentDb
Set qryActvChptrs = dbsChActv.QueryDefs("query100ActvChptrs")
Set qryActvRpts = dbsChActv.QueryDefs("query120ActvRpts")
Set rstActvChptrs = qryActvChptrs.OpenRecordset()
Set rstActvRpts = qryActvRpts.OpenRecordset()

rptImpDir = "C:\ChapterProcess\Import\"
rptImpTyp = ".xls"

strFullFileCPT = "C:\ChapterProcess\PhonyCover.xlsx"
strFileCPT = "PhonyCover.xlsx"
cvrSheet = "CTSheetName"

rstActvChptrs.MoveFirst 'first Chptr from query100ActvChptrs
Do While Not rstActvChptrs.EOF And Not rstActvChptrs.BOF 'Chptr loop, outer

    Dim xlCP As Excel.Application
    Dim arWb As Workbook
    Set xlCP = New Excel.Application

    xlCP.Workbooks.Open strFullFileCPT 'open cover template
    xlCP.Visible = True

    prevSheet = cvrSheet 'set prevSheet to cvrSheet name of strFullFileCPT. prevSheet becomes other added sheet names as they are added to the workbook.
    'depending on member items available, prevSheet is used for shuffling the tabs into report order seq query120ActvRpts

    Do While Not rstActvRpts.EOF And Not rstActvRpts.BOF

        rptPathFile = rptImpDir & LCase(rstActvChptrs![ChptrTag]) & " " & rstActvRpts![NameFile] & rptImpTyp
        rptFile = LCase(rstActvChptrs![ChptrTag]) & " " & rstActvRpts![NameFile] & rptImpTyp

'        Debug.Print rptPathFile
'        Debug.Print rptFile

        If Not Dir(rptPathFile, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then

            strChptrTag = UCase(rstActvChptrs![ChptrTag])
            strChptrName = (rstActvChptrs![Chptr])
            strReportTag = rstActvRpts![ReportTag]

            Set arWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=rptPathFile, ReadOnly:=True)

            Call mnpltRpts

            arWb.Close False

            prevSheet = rstActvRpts![ReportTag]
            Debug.Print rptFile & " Accommodated"

        Else
            Debug.Print "No file: " & rptFile
            rstActvRpts.MoveNext

        End If
        rstActvRpts.MoveNext
    Loop

    rstActvRpts.MoveFirst
    rstActvChptrs.MoveNext

    Call pdfRpt
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True

    xlCP.Quit
    Set xlCP = Nothing

Loop

End Sub


Private Sub mnpltRpts()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'>>Look<< subsequent times through the loop fail here.
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks(strFileCPT).Sheets(1)
'>>Look<< subsequent times through the loop fail here.

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=Sheets(prevSheet)

Call pgWidth

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = strReportTag

End Sub


Private Sub pgWidth()
On Error GoTo errHnd

Dim wkSht As Worksheet

Set wkSht = ActiveSheet

With wkSht.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With

errHnd:
End Sub


Private Sub pdfRpt()

bsPath = "C:\ChapterProcess\"
expPath = "Export\"
pdfPath = "PDF\"
strFile = "ProcessingReport"
strDate = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmm")
strExt = ".pdf"
expFileAll = bsPath & expPath & strDate & "_" & strChptrTag & "_" & strFile & strExt

    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    expFileAll _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

I have looked a good amount at the close/open threads and have been at it a while, but with my experience level, I think I could best benefit from another set of eyes. I look forward to your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to specify the workbook for Sheets("Sheet1"). If you use a variable wb as workbook in Private Sub mnpltRpts() like this: Private Sub mnpltRpts(wb as workbook) and then use wb.sheets("Sheet1"), It could help.

EDIT:
So in the loop, use this:

`Call mnpltRpts(arWb)`

And in change the sub to:

```
Private Sub mnpltRpts(wb as Workbook)

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks(strFileCPT).Sheets(prevSheet)
Call pgWidth
Workbooks(strFileCPT).Sheets("Sheet1").Name = strReportTag

End Sub
```

In this example I thought that the sheet would be moved and renamed in the new file. If it needs to be moved and renamed in the source file, it would be:

```
Private Sub mnpltRpts(wb as Workbook)

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks(strFileCPT).Sheets(1)
wb.sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=wb.sheets(prevSheet)
Call pgWidth
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = strReportTag

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I was able to specify as you suggested, and even added back into the original loop to see if anything got lost in the shuffle, and unfortunately, I get the same results - ok the first time through, fail on subsequent runs.

Comment: I have noticed since that when I open excel afterward, I occasionally find my second loop arWb report that way...

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Could it be because the sheetname is the same every time? Maybe if you change the name from "Sheet1" to a unique value after copying?

Comment: Thanks, Alex. At first, I received '9' out of range where I noted. After making the Private Sub mnpltRpts(arWb as workbook) update, I got '-2147417848(80010108)' object invoked has disconnected from its client. When I move the contents of mnpltRpts() back into the loop and avoid the call, I get the same '9' out of range in the same place. I appreciate your thoughts

Comment: Error 9 would probably mean that `Sheets("Sheet1")` does not exist. If you put a break on the line that fails, and then write the following line in the immediate window: `?Sheets(1).Parent.Name` what does it show?

Comment: "method not valid without a suitable object"

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you check if this code works?

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I appreciate your help. As I continue to sandpaper my forehead on this and research many resources, it seems more like it is a multiple instance Excel 2016 kind of issue. What you have suggested looks like it will work in 2010. I have tried copying tabs, copying/pasting text, trying to invoke Excel so I could use "ThisWorkbook" in a desperate moment, but for each, I have been successful only in the first loop - subsequent times through seem to fail because, presumably, because the xlCP instance that has opened PhonyCover the first time is not available to open it the next?

Comment: I totally missed that you are using a new Excel instance! Why is that if I may ask? Couldn't you just use `Application.Workbooks.open` for opening new workbooks?

Comment: I was not using a new instance on purpose. :) It seems like it might be a "feature" of 2016. The second time through the loop, the sheets from mnpltRpts were in a second instance that could not be referenced, and your workbooks.open suggestion turned me to it. It's chugging along like a breeze now. Thanks for helping me get this figured out.